# Best way to create Non-Random Questions for Quiz app - Swift

Tags: swift

New to swift and just wondering if anyone could give me some insight on the best way to create questions for a true or false quiz app I am working on.

I saw another thread about making questions non-random but as my expertise isn`t that great yet I am still struggling to understand the concepts.

Would I create a dictionary with a key value pair with a String being a question and Int being the answers?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the basic setup.  You might also consider using a Bool instead of an Int for the answer, and other fields for difficulty level, number of times used, etc.  The true power of dictionaries is that you can add as many key:value pairs as you like, thus being able to track all sorts of metrics over time.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Could you help give a quick run down of the code. My problem is I`m not exactly sure how to access those key value pairs and generate the question.

Comment: The best way is to create a Playground in Xcode and go through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html).  It is time well spent.  If you get stuck on a particular piece of code, post back to this thread.

Comment: Hi! 

I spent a good while watching tutorials and reading over the documentation. I am now well versed in creating dictionaries / arrays and accessing them / modifying them. 

But the problem I am facing is that I am not sure how to draw the question from my dictionary and display it to the user (through a UI label for example) then once they answer the question the next question is pulled from the dictionary and presented.

I have tried using for statements etc but I can`t work out for the life of me what to do.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  Do you have a UI?  Are all of your dictionaries in one array?  You will find much more useful information and responses by both searching and asking very specific, very focused questions.  Move forward one step at a time.

Comment: I just have 1 dictionary that has a question and its answer. Just for testing the UI is literally a UI label field and 2 button with 1 being True and the other being False. When you answer a question it moves onto the next question.

Comment: There are literally  hundreds of tutorials out there that can show you how to do such things.  Try [this one](http://ios-blog.co.uk/swift-tutorials/ios-8-swift-hello-world-and-introduction/) and [this one](http://swift.exomachina.com/swift-tutorial-4-responding-to-touch/)